# Give link to existing tags when asked to confirm creating a new one

Tags: feature-request

In creating a new tag, I've just been prompted:

> Check your spelling and make sure existing tags do not already cover the topic.

To increase quality by making things easier for users, could we have the text `existing tags` be a link to:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags ?

It took me a while to work out that `tags` is on the top navigation. It's generally not visible after typing in a question.